# Bash on Mac can't do **rm aFolder -rf**

Tags: bash

On Linux,  you can do like **rm -rf aFolder/**  or **rm aFolder -rf**

But On Mac you only can do like **rm -rf aFolder/**

Does anybody know what's the problem, or how to fix it?

---

Most Commands in Linux can do in the both way   **rm -rf aFolder/ or rm aFolder -rf**
But on Mac you can only do in the first way.

### I am wandering if you are really aware of the differences before you downvote this question. if you can try it both on Ubuntu and Mac!

I know FreeBSD/Mac and Ubuntu are different!
In Ubuntu, mostly commands can be executed like "rm aFolder -rf" rather than ALL. 
I am not mean all the commands too !. 
What I want is if there is a way to make "rm aFolder -rf" works in Mac OS X too,just like Ubuntu, **I think it will be convenient**

Comment: What problem?  All i see is programs from different OSes taking their args a bit differently.  That's normal.

Comment: `rm` is an external command (you can run `type rm` to verify that), so this isn't a question about Bash, but rather `/bin/rm` on OS X.

Comment: You can probably install GNU's version of rm with coreutils; the one included with OS X is the BSD version which has acted like this for many years.

Answer (score 2):

In Unix commands, the default has almost always been parameters first and directory/file names last. In fact, the Unix `C` library has two utilities: `getopt` and `getopt_long` that handle this for almost all Unix commands. I know in MS-DOS or Windows Console, the parameters could be mixed up:

```
C:> rd /s/q aFolder
C:> rd aFolder /s/q
```

That's because the `command.exe` shell doesn't do much in the way of file expansion. If commands do any expansion, they have to be written to do that.

Here's the problem you are talking about. Imagine if Unix commands could take parameters both ways:

```
$ touch -- -rf
$ mkdir aFolder
```

I have created a file named `-rf` and a folder named `aFolder`.

What should:

```
$ rm aFolder -rf
```

do?

Should it remove the directory aFolder? Should it remove the file `-rf`? Should both be removed or just one or the other?

In standard Unix, aFolder won't be removed (since you didn't specify the `-rf` parameters before the first non-parmameter name on the line. However, the file `-rf` will be removed. With the GNU version of `rm`, the exact opposite happens. That's very, very bad.

Mac OS X is 100% Unix, and is compliant with SUS 03. If something is allowed on GNU/Linux, but not on the Mac, it's due to the non-standard implementation of the tool in GNU. Some of the GNU implementations are nice. Others, like this one, I can do without.

Comment: have you tried the command in Ubuntu???!!
in Ubuntu rm -rf aFolder/ and rm aFolder -rf is the same !

Comment: @aelam - I'm sure it works, but it's a very bad idea. I haven't looked at the rm source code in GNU. It might be part of the coreutils package. Or, it could be something in the shell itself. I really didn't investigate. However, it's still a bad idea for the reason I pointed out: It breaks basic core Unix utility. If I had to classify this as a bug, I'd say the Mac is doing it right, and GNU got it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Different platforms often have their own implementations of the core utils, even though they seem to be the same, they often are quite different under the hood.

If it bothers you, you still can you busybox almost anywhere: http://busybox.net

Answer (score 0):

If you rely on the Linux behavior, you can install the GNU coreutils package. I thought it might be a difference in the underlying `getopt()` implementation, but GNU `rm` behaves just as you describe Linux `rm` even with the same libc.